# create AVD on Eclipse null error

Tags: android, sdk

I installed openjdk6, Java works normally, I installed Eclipse 64bit, Android-sdk-linux and extracted it, I set the location of Android-sdk but when I try to create an AVD, It appears in console : Android-sdk-manager null.

I can't find a solution on the net :/

Answer (score 0):

It may be due folder permission problem.

1. Open AVD Manager from Terminal (**`user@tech-ubuntu:~$ android avd`**)
2. Using the AVD Manager **create the new virtual device** and then click OK. An error window will appear which shows the **path** and **permission denied** message.
3. In terminal==>
   **`user@tech-ubuntu:~$ sudo chown -R root:root /path_specified`** 
   **`user@tech-ubuntu:~$ sudo chmod -R +r /path_specified`**
   where path is the **path_specified(eg: /home/user/.android/avd/)** in the error dialog.
4. Now create new device from AVD Manager through eclipse or directly from terminal ...
5. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Required libraries for 64-bit machines**:
If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

([source](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html))